# Why are contents of 2d array in C persisting through function calls?

Tags: c

I have the following file, the parts I am asking about are `float depth_buffer[1920][1076];` and the section toward the bottom labeled "fixes issue."

```
void draw_screen(cairo_t *cr, struct triangle_list triangles) {
    struct point_3d temp_points[3];
    struct point_3d projected_points[3];
    float shades[3] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    float depth_buffer[1920][1076];

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cairo_paint(cr);

    cairo_rectangle(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0);

    float d = 20;
    float v_w = 160;
    float v_h = 90;

    projected_points[0] = project_vertex(triangles.verteces[0], d, v_w, v_h);
    projected_points[1] = project_vertex(triangles.verteces[1], d, v_w, v_h);
    projected_points[2] = project_vertex(triangles.verteces[2], d, v_w, v_h);

    int current_triangle = 0;
    float color[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < triangles.num_triangles * 3; i += 3) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            projected_points[j] = project_vertex(triangles.verteces[i + j], d, v_w, v_h);
            shades[j] = triangles.shades[i + j];
        }

        color[0] = triangles.colors[current_triangle].r;
        color[1] = triangles.colors[current_triangle].g;
        color[2] = triangles.colors[current_triangle].b;

        draw_filled_triangle(cr, projected_points, shades, color, depth_buffer);

        current_triangle++;
    }
    
    // Fixes issue
    for (int i = 0; i < 1920; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1076; j++) {
            depth_buffer[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

When this function is called, all of the values in `depth_buffer` should be zero. However, when I used a debugger I discovered the values of `depth_buffer` were not zero, and appeared to be unchained from the last time it was called.

When added the loop to manually set all the values to zero, the issue went away.

Why isn't the memory for depth_buffer being cleared at the end of the function? Should I clear it manually, if so, how?

Comment: "When this function is called, all of the values in depth_buffer should be zero" Why? You didn't initialize it so the contents are whatever they are.

Comment: Using uninitialised variable can lead to any data stored there. You're not guaranteed to have zeroed local variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From C11 Standard#6.7.9p10 *[emphasis added]*

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is **indeterminate**. ...

The way you are trying to ensure the `depth_buffer` array should be cleared in subsequent call of `draw_screen()` function, by assigning `0.0` to all elements of `depth_buffer` array just before returning from `draw_screen()` function, is not going to help you out because `depth_buffer` is a automatic variable and objects with automatic storage duration live for the lifetime of the block in which they declared. The `depth_buffer` array declared in `draw_screen()` function block and it will gets destroyed upon exiting of `draw_screen()` function.

Instead, you should initialise the `depth_buffer` array elements with `0` before using it. To initialise all elements of `depth_buffer` array with `0`, you can do:

```
float depth_buffer[1920][1076] = {{0}};
```

Check more about array initialisation in C [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization).

The size of `depth_buffer` array is roughly around `8` `MB`. Allocating such a large array on the stack is bad practice and should be avoided. Instead, allocate memory dynamically to it. You may want to explore the [C memory management library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) functions.